# Private Route getting called dozens of times in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep having maximum update depth exceeded errors and I can't figure out why.

I have the following (pared down, it was more complex originally and actually rendered the component) private route in a private route file:

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
console.log("private route");
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withKeycloak(PrivateRoute));
```

And then in my index.js I have the following:

```
<Route
                render={({ location }) => {
                  const { pathname } = location;
                  return (
                    <TransitionGroup>
                      <CSSTransition
                        key={pathname}
                        classNames="page"
                        timeout={{
                          enter: 1000,
                          exit: 1000
                        }}
                      >
                        <Route
                          location={location}
                          render={() => (
                            <Switch>
                              <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                              <Route path="/signup/" component={Signup} />
                              <PrivateRoute
                                exact
                                path="/cards/"
                                component={Wrapper}
                              />
                              <PrivateRoute
                                exact
                                path="/"
                                component={Wrapper}
                              />
                             ...
```

This should, as far as I can tell, go to the `PrivateRoute` component for Wrapper on initial load, and then, redirect to the login page, which should **not** invoke the private route.

Instead, I see:

```
52 private route
```

in my console log.

Why am I being redirected back to `PrivateRoute` dozens of times? Shouldn't this happen once, and that's it?

There's no redirect to anywhere else on the login page at all. There is a login function, but that requires a button click, which is not happening.

Any idea on why this could be happening?

The error message:

```
in Lifecycle (created by Context.Consumer)
in Redirect (at PrivateRoute.js:11)
in PrivateRoute (created by Context.Consumer)
in WithKeycloak(PrivateRoute) (created by Context.Consumer)
in Connect(WithKeycloak(PrivateRoute)) (at src/index.js:114)
in Switch (at src/index.js:106)
in Route (at src/index.js:103)
in Transition (created by CSSTransition)
in CSSTransition (at src/index.js:95)
in div (created by TransitionGroup)
```

Originally, the routes looked more like this:

```js
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props =>
                    <Component {...props} />}

            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: is `PrivateRoute` a custom Component? If yes, then it's not handling `exact` prop. And then renders it in `/login` multiple times because `/` match `/login` also. This what is happening right?

Comment: Ok, I've removed it. Not what is causing the issue, though.

Comment: Ah, yes, that may be what is happening

Comment: removing it it's the same as before, the change is another, i will write an answer

Answer (score 0):

rather than

```
                   <PrivateRoute
                            component={Wrapper}
                          />
```

You want to do something like

```
                 <Route exact path="/" 
                        render=(props => (<PrivateRoute exact
                            path="/"
                            component={Wrapper}>)) />
```

Otherwise it will just always render your PrivateRoute

Comment: But, I want it to render my PrivateRoute on the first pass through, and redirect to login, and at that point it should not render PrivateRoute, because it is on the login route.

Comment: Your code generates an error when I am attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`Route` component is expected to receive a prop `exact` in order to only render this component when a match exists.

If not `exact` prop passed, will render it. And then if another match, with render both, and this is why you are getting redirected everytime.

Since you  are  using a custom component, you must handle this prop to provide it into the `Route` component.

to fix it, you can follow @TKol approach for example.

```
<Route exact path="/" 
  render=(props => (<PrivateRoute 
  path="/"
  component={Wrapper}>))
/>
```

This way `Route` is handling that for you and only will render 1 at time.

Comment: I think maybe this is less efficient than what I was doing in the original route inside the PrivateRoute -     {...this.props}

I'll edit to show

Comment: Not sure, but for the question purpose should fix infinite loop.

Comment: Exactly, and in `...rest` should come `exact` prop